# Wrong value of probingPath attribute in episerver.framework/scanAssembly node: 'modulesbin'. Attribute value should point to existing folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

I am developing MVC Site using EpiServer.  I created Site using this one tutorial  [EpiServer Commerce](http://world.episerver.com/Download/Items/EPiServer-Commerce/MVC-project-sample-package-for-EPiServer-75-Commerce/) And everything looks good, I created site in CMS/Admin, I can open CMS Edit, can open Commerce/Catalog but when I try to open COmmerce/Commerce Manager I got next error:

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.

Wrong value of probingPath attribute in episerver.framework/scanAssembly node: 'modulesbin'. Attribute value should point to existing folder.
```

[image]

modulesbin folder exist:

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for this in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="modulesbin" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And check the modulesbin folder exists in your site root

Comment: Checked, modulesbin exist in Web.config  and this foled exist in project too

Comment: <episerver configSource="episerver.config" />  exists in web.config too

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have multiple assemblyBinding sections, if so either remove some or add `<probing privatePath="modulesbin" />` to others